# Final DOOM: Evilution - MAP31: How to fix the missing yellow keycard?

Tags: doom-2

I'm playing through Final DOOM: Evilution and I've run into a game breaking bug on MAP31: Pharaoh.

Apparently it was released with the yellow keycard missing from the single-player version. There used to be a 3rd party fix, but the developer's website no longer works.

How can I fix this without resorting to noclipping through the yellow gate?

Comment: Any of the solutions on the wiki page addressing the issue work for your circumstance? https://doomwiki.org/wiki/MAP31:_Pharaoh_(TNT:_Evilution)

Comment: Also here's an archived copy of the patches page from that developer's website: https://web.archive.org/web/20160226213227/http://www.teamtnt.com/bugfixes.htm

Comment: @Venoda That wiki is how I found out about the bug in the first place. I'll give the archive.org a check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get any method suggested in the comments to work so I used the cheat code `IDKFA` to give myself the keycards.

Using noclip doesn't work as there are two triggers, the first is with the opening of the yellow gate.